# GeoServer Limit SLD editing functionality to certain users in GeoExplorer

Tags: geoserver, sld, boundless-suite

How would I go about preventing user X from editing layer styles? I have created a user in GeoServer that if they login they only see the layer preview screen. However as I am using the Boundless Suite (OpenGeo) if they add a new site in the GeoExplorer,they login and add a new point/ However the same use can also edit the style for that layer. I have hidden all the other layers, however this layer must be visible.

Is there a way to either remove the style editor from GeoExplorer? or prevent users from editing styles from the GeoServer side?

I did try creating a edit feature map using the OpenGeo SDK however found that adding the user login functionality pretty complex with little easy to follow documentation. I had all the functionality I required, as I could turn off the edit style feature, but then anyone who managed to access the layer would be able to add a new point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any user without administrative privileges should not be able to edit a style through GeoExplorer. As for disabling the style editor GeoExplorer is not recommended for these types of modifications and that gets into "building your own app" territory as you mention.

I suggest you pursue that route and try to post a more specific question about that. From your question it sounds like you needed a user that doesn't have edit privileges privileges for a specific layer. You can do that with the GeoServer security configuration.